# Почему после нажатия кнопки интерфейс фокусируется на курсоре?

Tags: android, activity

Приложение состоит из таблицы и кнопки под ней, таблица не вмещается полностью на дисплее, поэтому ее нужно прокрутить вниз, чтобы нажать на кнопку. После нажатия кнопки интерфейс прыгает сразу к месту, где стоял курсор в таблице. Как можно сделать так, чтобы после нажатия кнопки окно не прыгало к курсору?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эти два метода должны помочь

```
 button.setFocusable(true);
 button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: Проблема решена немного не до конца. setFocusable не работает вообще, а setFocusableInTouchMode работает как мне нужно, но на кнопку приходится нажать два раза, а не один раз. Из-за чего может не работать setFocusable?

Comment: первый метод ставит флаг, указывающий может ли элемент управления взять фокус, второй метод уже непосредственно ставит этот фокус. посмотри в подсказке, там есть еще 4 методa ими можно тоньше настроить фокус указав id view как параметр

Comment: Окей, спасибо, разберусь уже там.